# How to make uitableview indexes and sections from Array of stings

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an array of names I want to make section headers as alphabets such as A B C. Also the indexes. What's the most efficient way of making Sections out of an array of names

Comment: I have tried making it with nesting but that seems a heavy task... What's the easy and efficient way of doing it ?

Answer (score 2):

Here are i developed method that process on `NSArray` and created `NSDictionary` that you aspected.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray* internalArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc",@"xyz",@"aa",@"bb", nil];

    NSDictionary* dictStructued = [self sortArrayAndMakeStructur:internalArray];

   NSLog(@"Output : %@",dictStructued.description);

}
```

Here is your whole method..

```
-(NSMutableDictionary*)sortArrayAndMakeStructur:(NSArray*)array{

    NSMutableDictionary* dictIndexes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    NSArray* sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:
                                    @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    for (int i=0; i<[sortedArray count]; i++) {

        NSString* strName = sortedArray[i];
        if ([[dictIndexes allKeys] containsObject:[[strName substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]]) {
            NSMutableArray* internalArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictIndexes valueForKey:[[strName substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]]];
            [internalArray addObject:strName];

            [dictIndexes setObject:internalArray forKey:[[strName substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
        }
        else{
            NSMutableArray* internalArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:strName, nil];

            [dictIndexes setObject:internalArray forKey:[[strName substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];

        }

    }

    return dictIndexes;
}
```

Here section count  = `[[dictStructued allKeys] count];`

Number Of Row = `[[dictIndexes valueForKey:yourKey]  count];`

**Output** :

```
{
    A =     (
        aa,
        abc
    );
    B =     (
        bb
    );
    X =     (
        xyz
    );
}
```

Comment: @Asadullah Ali, let me know if you still stuck at some where..

Answer (score 0):

Please use nesting NSArray or NSDictionary that has array with each key.

Cited from:
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/

Comment: Thanks for reply.. What if I am getting that array of names from a web service ?  And the names containing only start with certain characters. I only want to display those section header which exist in the array..

Comment: use `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`  method.. I think customize this method is maybe efficient to make sections.

Comment: How will I calculate the number of sections ?

Comment: Based on first character of every string ?

Comment: Oh. I got your question mean. Sorry about my unefficient answer.So It seems you have to make the function that sort array of strings and make dictionary which have single character key that first character of string and string array as value of the key. That dictionary's array length will be numberof section.

Answer (score 0):

First, we sort them with alphabet:

```
NSMuatableArray* sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:
                           @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

and we populate it normally in `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Hope this could help.

Comment: How to calculate number of sections ?

Comment: please try `[self.tableview numberOfSections]`