# Swift get first letter from property in array of custom objects

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom object

```
class Keyword
{
    var keyword : String
    var description : String

    init(keywordID : Int, keyword : String, description : String)
    {
        self.keyword = keyword;
        self.description = description;
    }
}
```

And its data's like

```
var keywords = [Keyword]()
keywords.append(Keyword(keyword: "abc", description: "dsd dfgdf dghj"))
keywords.append(Keyword(keyword: "adet", description: "dsd dfgdf dghj"))
keywords.append(Keyword(keyword: "niuk", description: "dsd dfgdf dghj"))
keywords.append(Keyword(keyword: "sdg", description: "dsd dfgdf dghj"))
keywords.append(Keyword(keyword: "sax", description: "dsd dfgdf dghj"))
keywords.append(Keyword(keyword: "trygh", description: "dsd dfgdf dghj"))
```

For creating sections in UITableView, I need to have the first letter as the section title. For the above example I need the data as below

1. a -> abc, adet
2. n -> niuk
3. s -> sdg, sax
4. t -> trygh

I created another object to store the above data

```
class KeywordSection
{
    var section : Character
    var keywords : [Keyword]

    init(section : Character, keywords : [Keyword])
    {
        self.section = section;
        self.keywords = keywords;
    }
}
```

I did this in Android by looping through the array and extract the first letter and checking the sections. Also I need to check if the first letter is alphabet, if so I have to add that section, else the section will be '#' (same as that of iphone contacts app)

Comment: Can you use Objective c methods in your swift project using Bridge?

Comment: @PavanJangid sorry man, I can only use swift methods, or I need to write custom methods

Comment: You can get reference from this link, and you have to convert code from objective c to swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342542/how-to-split-nsarray-into-uitableview-sections-alphabetically
See last ans in above link

Comment: Here is Swift code for your question. http://nshipster.com/uilocalizedindexedcollation/

Comment: @Sajeel, i have replied on same question on four days ago. but that is in objective - c. i think you don't  face too much difficult to convert objective - c to swift. here are the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201038/how-to-make-uitableview-indexes-and-sections-from-array-of-stings/31203287#31203287

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this method to your keyword class:

```
var sectionName : String {
    return keyword.substringToIndex(1) ?? "?"
}
```

Then use this code to create the dictionary of section headers to keywords:

```
var sections = [String:[Keyword]]()

for k in keywords {
    let s = k.sectionName
    if let oldKeywords = sections[s] {
        var mutableOldKeywords = oldKeywords
        mutableOldKeywords.append(k)
        sections[s] = mutableOldKeywords
    } else {
        sections[s] = [k]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aderstedt. Also the newly created sections dictionary is not in sorted order, how to attain sorting in that

Comment: A dictionary isn't sorted, but you can get the sorted keys using `sections.keys.array.sorted(<)`

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4:

```
let newArray = arrayName.map{Array($0.name)[0]}
```

This will be character array. Use below syntax for get string.

```
String(newArray[index])
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays (Swift 4+) grouping to sections became very comfortable

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: keywords, by: { String($0.keyword.first!) })
```

and map it to a `KeywordSection` array

```
let sections = grouped.map({ KeywordSection(section: Character($0.0), keywords: $0.1) }).sorted{$0.section < $1.section}
```